# PAGE.USER missing in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is available in ASP.NET MVC, because I see other people talking about using it.

However, when I type Page., the intellisense gives me only these 3 options :

CreateHtmlTextWriterFromType
Equals
ReferenceEquals

What do you think is going on?

EDIT: If I do `Page page = new Page()`, then `page.User` works.  Is it really needed?

Answer (score 4):

You can access it in Controller :`HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`
You  can acces it in view like this :`<% if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){} %>`
Hope this helps.

Comment: And from a master page you can use Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Answer (score 1):

`Page` is a Webforms object, not much help in MVC.  You can access the authenticated user from the HTTP Context, something like `httpcontext.user.identity`